# How to describe a fileheader with doxygen-markdown flavor

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I'm writing a code style guide in markdown of a Doxygen project and have to describe which information are needed in a new file. I want to put in an example of a file header. But I don't get the example working.

What I want:

```
/**
 * @file
 * @brief Provides ...
 * @copyright ...
 */
```

And I get this:

```
/**
 *
```

I have tried several things like masking of some/all `*` and `\`. I have tried it with `~~~` and ```` ``` ````. `<pre>...</pre>` and `<code>...</code>` and variants with all of this, but without success.

The Doxyfile doesn't differ much from the default one generated via `doxygen -s -g`:

`+PROJECT_NAME           = "Coding Guidlines"
-PROJECT_NAME           = "My Project"
 PROJECT_NUMBER         =
 PROJECT_BRIEF          =
 PROJECT_LOGO           =
@@ -171,7 +171,7 @@ INPUT_FILTER           =
 FILTER_PATTERNS        =
 FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
 FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
+USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = introduction.md
-USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE =
 #---------------------------------------------------
 # Configuration options related to source browsing
 #---------------------------------------------------
@@ -231,7 +231,7 @@ QHG_LOCATION           =
 GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
 ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
 DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
+GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
-GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO`

Used doxygen version is `1.8.14`. Doxyfile and testfile in the same directory.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: what are the settings in your ```Doxyfile``` (doxygen configuration file that are different from the standard settings from ```doxygen -g```? What is the name of your file? Where are the files located and where is doxygen started?

Comment: Thanks @albert, I have added a diff to an original Doxyfile and have added informations about my used doxygen version.

Comment: is the name of the file ```testfile```try ```testfile.h``` (I know that it is not a source file but just to get the process going. Also have a look at ```EXTENSION_MAPPING``` in the ```Doxyfile```.